# Scrape InnerText from body of website C#

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to gather the data from this website: http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=f2pshrympy

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;

var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
var document = webGet.Load("http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=f2pshrympy");
var bodyText = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/text()");
Console.WriteLine(bodyText);
Console.ReadLine();
```

When the program is run nothing is printed to the console and there are no errors.

[screenshot of the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxD9Z.png)

I'm guessing that nothing is being found with the XPath "/html/body/text()", any ideas how I can go around fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page is pure text. So you don't need any tool like *HtmlAgilityPack* to parse it. Just download it and use it.

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
    var bodyText = wc.DownloadString("http://services.runescape.com/m=hiscore_oldschool/index_lite.ws?player=f2pshrympy");

}
```